# Magento 2.2.6. How to show custom text after tabs section in product page?

Tags: magento2, layout, product-attribute, tabs

I want to show custom content on product page below the tabs section.

Basically I moved tabs and related product section in product info main area (right side) and now I want to add a custom content after tabs.

How to create a new .phtml file and call after tabs?
Thanks

[image]

**Edit**

```
<body>
     <referenceBlock name="product.price.final" remove="true"/>
     <move element="product.info.stock.sku" destination="product.info.main" before="page.main.title" />
     <move element="breadcrumbs" destination="product.info.stock.sku" before="-" />
     <move element="product.info.social" destination="product.info.media" after="-" />
    <move element="product.info.details" destination="product.info.main" after="product_options_wrapper_bottom"/>
    <move element="catalog.product.related" destination="product.info.main" after="product_options_wrapper_bottom"/>
<referenceContainer name="product.info.main">
        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="custom" after="product.info.details" template="product/view/giftitems.phtml"/>
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
```

Comment: Can you update your catalog_product_view.xml to your question?

Comment: You have to overwrite catalog_product_view.xml file into your design folder and add new block to display your html content

Comment: Can you check my answer?

Answer (score 2):

Create a file with name **catalog_product_view.xml** under below path:

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

add content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="product.info.main">
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="custom" after="product.info.details" template="product/view/text.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Now create one file with name **text.phtml** under below path:

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/text.phtml

with content:

```
<?= __('Custom Text') ?>
<?php $_product = $block->getProduct(); //You can also use current product object by this code if needed. ?>
```

**EDIT:**

```
<body>
<referenceBlock name="product.price.final" remove="true"/>
<move element="product.info.stock.sku" destination="product.info.main" before="page.main.title" />
<move element="breadcrumbs" destination="product.info.stock.sku" before="-" />
<move element="product.info.social" destination="product.info.media" after="-" />
<move element="product.info.details" destination="product.info.main" after="product.info.overview"/>
<move element="catalog.product.related" destination="product.info.main" after="product.custom"/>

<referenceContainer name="product.info.main">
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.custom" after="product.info.details" before="catalog.product.related" template="product/view/giftitems.phtml"/>
</referenceContainer>
</body>
```

Comment: Working but showing before the tabs section, not after.

Comment: Can you update your xml file to the question so that I can understand?

Comment: I am not asking to update my given xml, I am asking to update your catalog_product_view.xml on which you have moved the tab section to right.

Comment: See my edit xml.

Comment: How did you move your tabs to right column? That code is not there in the xml?

Comment: My mistake. I added tabs & related products xml in Magento _Theme default.xml file.Now I added in catalog_product_view.xml.See edits.

Comment: Check my edited answer. Use that content for your xml .

Comment: I added your code but now tabs are showing after related products.

Comment: Fixed. I added this <move element="product.info.details" destination="product.info.main" after="product.info.overview"/>  to fix this issue.Thanks for help.

Comment: Which command need to run after any file changes (css, js or xml)?

Comment: Run this command: php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f. Also accept the answer if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Add catalog_product_view.xml in your custom theme at below path and content:

> app/design/frontend/{{package}}/{{theme}}/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="product.info.main">
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="custom-text" template="product/view/custom.phtml" after="product.info.details"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Add file custom.phtml at path

> app/design/frontend/{{package}}/{{theme}}/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/custom.phtml

with required text/code.

Comment: I tried but not showing anything.

Comment: Updated my answer, check it.

Comment: I want to show something after product.info.detail can i use this?

Comment: Yes, you can use above, however, let me know if it doesn't help..